# HTML insert in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I am trying to create html statement in ruby.
Here is my sample code.

```
tmp1 = "<div><font face='Arial'><span style='font-size:9pt'>&diams;Issue : #{@issue[:"Defect Type"]} (#{@issue[:"Checker"]}) found in #{@issue[:"Function"]}</span></font></div>"        
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(tmp1)
doc.to_html
header = Nokogiri::XML.fragment('<html><body>')
header.at('body').children = doc
details = header.to_html

doc = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse(details)
body = doc.at('body')        

url = "http://collab.temp.com/main/display/CQ/Checker+Guides"
tmp2 = "<div><font face='Arial'><span style='font-size:9pt'>&diams;Review Guide : <a href=#{url}>#{url}</a></span></font></div>"                    

body.add_child(tmp2)
details = doc.to_html(:encoding => 'EUC-KR')
```

When I display 'details' in browser, I can an exact hyper link like below:

♦Review Guide : http://collab.temp.com/main/display/CQ/Checker+Guides

But, if I click the link, 'The Webpage cannot be found' error occurs.

If I copy the link and then paste it in browser, I can access to it successfully.

So I think that I may create wrong html statement in ruby.

Could you help me for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `url` attribute of `a` anchor tag (within `tmp2 =` line) with quotes:

```
<a href=#{url}>#{url}</a> ⇐ incorrect
<a href='#{url}'>#{url}</a> ⇐ correct
```

Comment: Actually, I've already tried both quotes and double quotes. But I couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML as by Browser»ViewSource?

Comment: I found out the cause of this issue. Our system is blocking execution of hyper link. So I cannot access it by click. Thanks for your support, @mudasobwa